SFTP requires MFA whenever I upload/download files, but not with SSHFS
I'm using my university's server for my work, which requires me to manipulate files frequently. The server is secured with Duo MFA, so every time I log in, I need to go through the MFA process.
On my Linux machine, I use SSHFS to mount one of the folders. I run a simple shell command every morning to mount the server folder locally, and then I can forget about it.
However, on Windows, it requires MFA every time I try to upload or download a file. My preferred tool, MobaXterm, prompts for MFA each time, and FileZilla asks for it initially, then again if I become inactive for 1 minute (with the log showing 'Disconnected from server').
After trying multiple blog posts and solutions (like this one: Keep SFTP Connection Active to Avoid Dual-Factor Reauthentication), it seems that each upload/download triggers a fresh SSH connection, which inevitably requires MFA.
I've tried adjusting the keepalive settings in MobaXterm and the general .ssh/config file, but without success.
Is there a solution to prevent frequent MFA prompts? I don’t understand why SSHFS doesn’t require frequent MFA but other methods do.
Alternatively, if you’re using a different method to navigate and manipulate files on a Linux server with MFA, I’d appreciate any recommendations.

If I were to guess SSHFS connection isn’t timing out. MobaXTerm probably has a setting but I have never used it in the way your using it

Does using an SSH keypair bypass MFA? It does on some packages but not on others.

Thanks for the comment!
@Ramhound : Yes, I think so too. But I couldn't find the settings for that...

Thanks for the comment! @doneal24: Nop. The authentication only works with SSH keypair AND MFA..
